# Meteor.call method not found

Tags: javascript, methods, meteor

I am working my way through the Microscope project in Discover Meteor and I have hit a problem. I am getting a 'Method not found' error for the following code:

HTML Template - microscope/client/templates/posts/post_submit.html

```
<template name="postSubmit">
<form class="main form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="url">URL</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="url" id="url" type="text" value="" placeholder="Your URL" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="title" id="title" type="text" value="" placeholder="Name your post" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>

</form>
```

JS - microscope/client/templates/posts/post_submit.js

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post = {
       url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
       title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
    };

    Meteor.call('postInsert', post, function(error, result) {
        // display the error to the user and abort
        if (error)
            return alert(error.reason);
            Router.go('postPage', {_id: result._id});  
        });
    }
});
```

I am not sure how to debug this as I am getting no errors in the console. Please can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have a method called `postInsert` in your server side code..if it is there then share the server side code so that it will be easy to figure out the issue.

Comment: can you show how and where you define your methods?

Comment: Make sure you have added your method postInsert. If you dont know how look at the meteor docs. http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-methods. If you have the method then tell us what is your method so we see what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Very likely that you need to add the method `postInsert` to the server side. If you're following along in Discover Meteor, they do that in the next section - https://book.discovermeteor.com/chapter/creating-posts

For example, you put the method in a file called `lib/collections/posts.js` like this

```
Meteor.methods({
  postInsert: function(postAttributes) {
    check(Meteor.userId(), String);
    check(postAttributes, {
      title: String,
      url: String
    });
```

Comment: Please consider adding more details to your post.  In the event that your links change or become unavailable, your answer will not be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!